# R markdown Page Breaks from Function

Tags: r, pdf, latex, markdown

I am trying to break to a new page from a R markdown document that is calling a function to produce a set of graphics for each set of data (400+ pages in some cases). I am using LaTeX.

Any ideas? Here is a simple example that demonstrates some my challenge though it doesn't use a function to produce the output.

````
---
title: "Test Page Break"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}
summary(cars)
cat("\\pagebreak")
print(cars)
```
````

**Update #1:**
My example didn't demostrate the use of a function within the code chunk. Here is a better example.

````
---
title: "Test Page Break"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}
pr_w_pagebreak <- function() {
print(summary(cars))
cat("\\pagebreak")
print(cars)
}
pr_w_pagebreak()
```
````

Answer (score 2):

The trouble you'll have with your chunks is that you want some results to appear as 'markup' and some to appear 'asis'.  If you want to get the page break with the single block as you have it, you will need to do:

````
```{r, echo=-2}
summary(cars)
knitr::asis_output("\\pagebreak")
print(cars)
```
````

Otherwise, you'll have to do

````
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

\pagebreak

```{r}
print(cars)
```
````

And as Floo0 points out, you can get LaTeX code from the R chunks if you use `results = 'asis'`, but you have to be careful because the following will **not** give you what you want.

`````
```{r, results='asis'}
summary(cars)
cat("\\pagebreak")
print(cars)
````
`````

Comment: This code works directly in the code chunk, but not as part of a function. I will revise my question with a more accurate example. Would love some guidance with getting page break in a function within a code chunk.